# Using mutiple IIF with LIKE conditions in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression, sql-like, iif

I have an expression using multiple IIF but for some reason, every record is listed as "Immunized" in the column perhaps I might have done something wrong in this query. I really appreciate your help in resolving this

```
=IIF(Fields!CompliantWith.Value like "*Declin*", "Valid Declination - " & IIF(Fields!DeclinationValue.Value <> nothing,Fields!DeclinationValue.Value, "Not Specified"),
IIF(Fields!CompliantWith.Value like "*Contraindication*", "Medical Contraindication - " & IIF(Fields!ContraindicationValue.Value <> nothing,Fields!ContraindicationValue.Value, "Not Specified"),
IIF(Fields!CompliantWith.Value like "*Exemp*", "Valid Exemption - " & IIF(Fields!ExemptionValue.Value <> nothing,Fields!ExemptionValue.Value, "Not Specified"),
IIF(Fields!CompliantWith.Value like "*Immunize*", "Immunized",""))))
```

[image: Report]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `like` with `.Contains` and remove the *'s

Like is not supported directly in SSRS expressions as far as I know.

so this

```
Fields!CompliantWith.Value like "*Declin*"
```

would become this

```
Fields!CompliantWith.Value.Contains("Declin")
```

You might also want to consider using =SWITCH for situations like this, it's much easier to read than nested IIF's